# Pulling information into xml file for each user

Tags: php, xml, event-receiver

I want to make my database pull information for each user for example in a link like `www.example.com/user/22/xml`

I want to pull information from my database and into that XML file that way I can basically put a snippet on another website an pull that XML data onto a page on another domain.

I have tried making it make an XML file when the users complete registration but I'm really not looking for that route because the users that already have an account won't have an XML file created

i have changed my route on this looks like i have ran into a wall im now looking to just put my xml into my existing php page then being able to pull the information on another domain i have my source code with what im working with now

This image is what is on my php page on the site the xml would be coming from
https://i.postimg.cc/tgwCQ0YJ/1.png

This image is what im calling on the other domain
https://i.postimg.cc/c17kPQzG/2.png

im really getting nowhere either way

Comment: More information would be helpful to provide  a proper solution.
however if you just want to read a record from database and output it as xml, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml

Comment: I have changed my course on making this happen im just now trying on adding my xml code into my php page then being able to pull data from that url ip osted code below as an answer